# Doctrine2 One-to-Many Relationship's not working . Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many

This is what I want to achieve using Doctrine2 in Symfony.

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/97g8z In this link you'll find an image of the ER Model.

So, these are my classes:

```
class Pais
{
/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string $nombre
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nombre", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $nombre;
...
```

This is the class Ciudadano:

```
class Ciudadano
{
/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string $nombre
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nombre", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $nombre;
```

This is the class Nacionalidad, which is in the middle:

```
class Nacionalidad
{

/**
 * @var integer $idpais
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Pais")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 */
private $idpais;

/**
 * @var integer $idciudadano
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ciudadano")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 */
private $idciudadano;

/**
 * @var date $fecha
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="fecha", type="date")
 */
private $fecha;
...
```

After this command:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:create
```

Doctrine generates this SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Ciudadano (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, nombre VARCHAR(255) NOT
NULL, apellido VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Nacionalidad (id INT NOT NULL, fecha DATE NOT NULL, descripcion VAR
CHAR(255) NOT NULL, INDEX IDX_8B2C843BBF396750 (id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = I
nnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Pais (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, nombre VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE Nacionalidad ADD CONSTRAINT FK_8B2C843BBF396750 FOREIGN KEY (id) REF
ERENCES Ciudadano(id);
```

So I have these doubts:

- Why Doctrine2 doesn't create the foreign key that references the table Pais?
- Why Doctrine2 doesn't create the alter table to indicate that attributes on table nacionalidad 'idpais' and 'idciudadano' are primary keys of that table?
- Do I have to tell Doctrine the type of a field that is a foreign key? (Or Doctrine2 guesses the type?)
- All I see in my tables are One-to-Many relationships. Why would I need Many-to-One? I'd like to understand.

I need help with this please. Maybe:

- I'm not writing the right annotations on my classes, or
- I'm not getting the concept.

---

So, I kept trying and found that I could achieve what I wanted using this annotation:

```
class Nacionalidad
{

/**
 * @var integer $idpais
 * @ORM\Id 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Pais", inversedBy="Nacionalidad")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idpais", referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 */
private $idpais;

/**
 * @var integer $idciudadano
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ciudadano", inversedBy="Nacionalidad")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idciudadano", referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 */
private $idciudadano;

/**
 * @var date $fecha
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="fecha", type="date")
 */
private $fecha;
```

Pais and Ciudadano tables are the same. I didn't change anything in them (I don't know if this has something to do with the problem I have).

The test I did was:
After telling doctrine to create the tables I went to phpmyadmin and confirmed that the tables and the relationships were what I wanted. And yes they were. But:

I'm trying to insert a row on Nacionalidad:

```
$nacionalidad->setidpais('1');
$nacionalidad->setidciudadano('1');
$nacionalidad->setfecha('1989-02-01');
$nacionalidad->setdescripcion('Hola');
```

I'm sure a row in table pais with id 1 exists, and I'm sure a row in table ciudadano with id 1 exists.

I'm getting this error:

> Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string
>   given in
>   C:\wamp\www\sym\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php line
>   1218

I believe there is a problem with the annotations and the relationships. I believe maybe I'm not doing it like it should be done. Do you have any suggestions? I'm LOST.

Comment: Are you trying to create Many to Many relation with extra fields in the middle table (nacionalidad)?

Comment: Hello, I think that fecha means birthdate in spanish (I'm french, so not sure). If yes, why not store it in the Ciudadano entity? You could then simplify these annotations...

Comment: Fecha means date, it could be any date (birthday is fecha de nacimiento or cumpleaños). So I can't store it in Ciudadano because it's not what I want. However thanks for helping :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you problem lies elsewhere. If you want to bind two entities in such way, you need to shift all you logic towards objects by assigning them and not their primary key values. That will Symfony take care of.

That being said you should:

```
$pais = ... // either create new Pais object or retrieve it from db
$ciudadano = ... // same as above
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '1989-02-0'); // no Date class in PHP, but I think this will work...

$nacionalidad->setidpais($paid);
$nacionalidad->setidciudadano($ciudadano);
$nacionalidad->setfecha($date);
$nacionalidad->setdescripcion('Hola'); // this is *simple* type so this can go like this
```

I would, but by no means is necessary, rename those attributes and getters/setters and remove "id" from it as you are now, technically speaking, managing objects, not ids.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks buddy. I solved it and it was what you said, plus I didn't know how to work with doctrine relationships because I didn't understand them, and I was making mistakes, but I read a little bit more, and it was fine. :)

Comment: Oh silly me, I didn't even look at the date of your question. I would assume that you have solved your problem. Glad you have :)

Comment: I'm sure your answer would be helpful to others ;). So, it's not too late.